# Push notification certificate generation

Tags: cocoa-touch, push-notification

We succesfully set up and tested the sandbox Push notification certificate, now we are going to test the production certificate. We generated it in the same way as the development, and changed the apple adrress to the proper push notification service. But we don't get the push somehow although we even builded the app for distribution. I've heard also that the device tokens should be different to test production, what does it mean? Do I have to test on other devices?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device token will be different for the distribution certificate so the app have to send new token to the server (the one you receive in [didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)).

Also make sure your distribution mobileprovisioning profile does have "aps-environment" string in it set to "production". If not - recreate the mobileprovisioning profile for the app.